# Export sentiment.metadata from pyspark sparknlp

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, nlp

I have a sparknlp preprocessing pipeline from which I extract several features by making use of pretrained models.

Everything works as expected but for some reason I cannot get to the metadata element generated by  `SentimentDLModel.pretrained(name='sentimentdl_use_twitter', lang="en")`.

I tried to access it through SQL Transformer, subsequent UDF etc. etc.

It always fails with:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 540.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 540.0 (TID 6088) (10.179.24.252 executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function (Annotation$$$Lambda$3527/709774432: (array<map<string,string>>) => array<string>)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.serializefromobject_doConsume_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.sort(UnsafeExternalRowSorter.java:225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$.$anonfun$prepareShuffleDependency$10(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:376)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
```

I have the strong feeling that I'm using the finisher wrong, maybe its something completely different.

Here is my pipeline and execution of it:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from sparknlp.annotator import *
from sparknlp.base import *
from pyspark.ml.feature import CountVectorizer, IDF, StopWordsRemover, SQLTransformer
import os
from sparknlp.annotator import LanguageDetectorDL


# Create Preprocessing Pipeline
def create_pipeline():
    document_assembler = DocumentAssembler() \
        .setInputCol('lyrics') \
        .setOutputCol('lyrics') 

    #define language detector
    language_detector = LanguageDetectorDL.pretrained()\
        .setInputCols(["lyrics"])\
        .setOutputCol("language")
    
    # define sentence detector
    sentence = SentenceDetector() \
        .setInputCols(["lyrics"]) \
        .setOutputCol("sentences")
    
    # # Define universal sentence encoder
    sentence_embeddings = UniversalSentenceEncoder.pretrained(name="tfhub_use", lang="en")\
        .setInputCols(["sentences"])\
        .setOutputCol("sentence_embeddings")

    # Define sentiment detector on sentence level
    sentiment_detector= SentimentDLModel.pretrained(name='sentimentdl_use_twitter', lang="en")\
        .setInputCols(["sentence_embeddings"])\
        .setOutputCol("sentiment")
    
    # SQL Transformer
    sentiment_query = "SELECT *, sentiment.metadata as sentiment_numerical FROM __THIS__"

    #exract sentiment score
    sentiment_transformer = SQLTransformer(statement=sentiment_query)
        
    
    # Define the word tokenizer
    tokenizer = Tokenizer()\
        .setInputCols(['sentences'])\
        .setOutputCol('tokens')
    
    # POS tagger
    pos = PerceptronModel.pretrained("pos_ud_ewt", "en") \
        .setInputCols(["lyrics", "tokens"]) \
        .setOutputCol("pos")

    # Define the lemmatizer
    lemmatizer = LemmatizerModel.pretrained()\
        .setInputCols(['tokens'])\
        .setOutputCol('lemma')
    
    # Define the normalizer
    normalizer = Normalizer()\
        .setInputCols(['lemma'])\
        .setOutputCol('normalized')\
        .setLowercase(True)
    
        
    # # Define the finisher
    finisher = Finisher()\
        .setInputCols(['lyrics','language','sentences','sentence_embeddings','tokens','pos','normalized', 'sentiment', 'sentiment_numerical'])\
        .setOutputCols(['lyrics','language','sentences','sentence_embeddings','tokens','pos','normalized', 'sentiment', 'sentiment_numerical'])\
        .setIncludeMetadata(True)\
        .setParseEmbeddingsVectors(True)\
        .setOutputAsArray(True)
        
        
    # Define the stop words
    stopwords = set(StopWordsRemover.loadDefaultStopWords('english'))

    # Define the stopword remover
    sw_remover = StopWordsRemover()\
        .setInputCol('normalized')\
        .setOutputCol('filtered')\
        .setStopWords(list(stopwords))

    # Define count vectorizer for raw data
    count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(
        inputCol='filtered',
        outputCol='tf', minDF=10
    )

    # Define TF-IDF
    tfidf = IDF(
        inputCol='tf',
        outputCol='tfidf',
        minDocFreq=10
    )

    # Define the pipeline
    text_processing_pipeline = Pipeline(
        stages=[
            document_assembler,
            language_detector,
            sentence,
            sentence_embeddings,
            sentiment_detector,
            sentiment_transformer,
            tokenizer,
            pos,
            lemmatizer,
            normalizer,
            finisher,
            sw_remover,
            count_vectorizer,
            tfidf
])

    return text_processing_pipeline
```

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, element_at
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType

print('Creating the pipeline...') 
# Create the text processing pipeline
pipeline = create_pipeline()

print('Fitting the pipeline...')
# Fit the pipeline with the data
model = pipeline.fit(multi_df)

print('Transforming the DataFrame...')
# Transform the DataFrame with the text processing steps
processed_df = model.transform(multi_df).repartition(100)

print('Cleaning the output...')
# Register the udf to enforce output compatibility
clean_output_udf = udf(clean_output, ArrayType(StringType()))

# Define a UDF to extract the values from the map and cast them to string
extract_values_udf = udf(lambda m: [str(element_at(m, i)) for i in range(1, len(m) + 1)], ArrayType(StringType()))


# Clean the output 
processed_df = processed_df.select(
    'id',
    clean_output_udf('artist').alias('artist_name'),
    clean_output_udf('name').alias('song_name'),
    clean_output_udf('lyrics').alias('lyrics'),
    clean_output_udf('language').alias('language'),
    clean_output_udf('sentences').alias('sentences'),
    clean_output_udf('tokens').alias('tokens'),
    clean_output_udf('pos').alias('pos'),
    clean_output_udf('normalized').alias('normalized'),
    'filtered',
    'tf',
    'tfidf',
    'danceability',
    'energy',
    'key',
    'loudness',
    'mode',
    'speechiness',
    'acousticness',
    'instrumentalness',
    'liveness',
    'valence',
    'tempo',
    'duration_ms',
    'time_signature',
    'sentiment',
    'sentiment_numerical'
)



try:
    processed_df.write.format('parquet').save('../data/preprocessed/parquet', mode='overwrite')
    print('Saved the preprocessed data to parquet.')
except Exception as e:
    # Print the full stack trace of the exception
    print(e)
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
```

I tried to extract the metadata next to the results of the sentimentDL model, store it in a parquet file for further processing.